# How can I deposit metallic electrodes on a temperature-sensitive wafer?

Tags: process, clean-room, microfabrication

How can I deposit metallic contacts on a wafer in a process that won't heat the wafer above 80C? The size of the electrodes should be around 1mm<sup>2</sup>.

The wafer could be glass or silicon, coated with a sensitive organic/polymeric film, functioning as a dielectric layer.

Comment: Could you use Sputter Deposition?

Comment: Conductive silver (metallic silver) paint?

Comment: @BrianDrummond silver paint is toluene based, which dissolves the present film, and water-based silver ink oxidises too fast.

Comment: Perhaps electrolysis if you first doped the area with a conductive material.

Comment: Perhaps use Woods Metal as solder then?

Comment: Copper electroplating?

Comment: @BrandenBoucher Wouldn't the wafer become hot due to the plasma?

Comment: Are you interested in the behavior of the film, or is there something in the wafer you're testing, and the film is a protective coating?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the film has a function and the electrode needs to be deposited on the film.

Comment: Turn the problem inside out. Deposit the contacts on the wafer, then lay down the film, then dissolve holes in the film to allow connection with the contacts. Make the connection holes smaller than the contacts, so there is an overlap of film over outer portions of the contacts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast sorry I didnt mention before: the film is a dielectric layer separating between a top electrode and a bottom electrode. question updated.

Comment: So the film is non-conductive? In that case just use any epoxy that won't dissolve the film.

Comment: @BrianDrummond isn't Wood's metal super toxic?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it personally but I know you can get conductive epoxy, you could probably use this to bond wires on without heat.

One such option
http://www.mgchemicals.com/products/adhesives/electrically-conductive/silver-conductive-epoxy-8331/